# Fullscreen and volume button not showing on embedded vimeo video.

Tags: html, magento

I'm trying to get a vimeo video to show the fullscreen button instead of double clicking.

This is the code:

```
<div class="video-container"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/177132713?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" frameborder="0" width="640" height="480" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to change the settings fot the specifik video on Vimeo. Make sure that "Show Fullscreen Button" is checked under the tab "Embed".

Take a look here: https://memberful.com/images/blog/vms-vimeo-player-preferences-ad71d4b5.png

Note that this is only possible if you own the video.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not own the videos that I have embedded on the website so I guess double clicking will be the only option for now.

Comment: Hello again Leroy! You can allways contact the owner of the video and ask them to change this settings for you. I would really recommend this because there are laws in some countries that says that you must have the owners permission to add links to their work. You could ask them for this at the same time.